# routes.rb not routing to correct controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building the ruby/rails tutorial and I created the `welcome#index` view file and its controller. I have also uncommented the `root :to => "welcome#index"` section of `routes.rb` and deleted `public/index.html` and restarted the server.

But for some reason I am getting the `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.` error. Does anyone know what would cause this?

Here's `routes.rb`:

```
Quirk::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"

root :to => "welcome#index"

end
```

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
```

Comment: did you create the WelcomeController in apps/controller? what does "$> bundle exec rake routes | grep welcome" returns?

Comment: and if you have a `WelcomeController` does it have an `index` method??? also does it have a matching view in `app/views/welcome/index.*`

Comment: @NicolasGarnil I have welcome_controller.rb which was created automatically from the generate. Here's what your query returns: welcome_index GET /welcome/index(.:format) {:controller=>"welcome", :action=>"index"}

Comment: @bjhaid - I do have welcome_controller.rb - and it has def index. Is that good enough? That's what was generated by generate. Also, yes I have the correct view file.

Comment: post your routes.rb file please

Comment: @NicolasGarnil Added in question.

Comment: did you restart your server

Comment: @bjhaid I did restart the server

Comment: change `root :to => "welcome#index"` to `root "welcome#index"` restart your server and see if it works

Comment: @bjhaid just tried and no success.

Comment: @NicolasGarnil I actually also got this little notice when I ran the query you sent : `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`('` only problem is I don't have a parentheses anywhere in my controller, view, or route.

Comment: can you post your `WelcomeController` and your `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` files

Comment: @bjhaid posted in the question.

Comment: @itamar it should be `index.html.erb` and not `index.html.rb`

Comment: @bjhaid sorry it IS index.html.erb - my typo sorry!

Comment: @itamar please post your server logs for the request

Comment: @itamar where is your index.html.erb located? (should be  app/views/welcome/index.html.erb).

Comment: @rlecaro2 that's exactly where it is. This is getting pretty frustrating. I seem to have done everything right.

Comment: To discard any caching issues you should restart the server, browser, and ultimately your system. What is the url you're using?

Comment: Post the error details and trace please

Comment: This is the error I get. how do I get the trace? Sorry, fairly new. `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.`

Comment: Where are you running the app? That's a generic 404 error message. In development mode the error detail and trace should appear in the browser, if you're running it locally. Check the config/environments/development.rb file: should have this line:
config.consider_all_requests_local = true

Comment: @jinavar1 I do have that line in the `development.rb` file. I am running it on Dreamhost using Passenger. Does that make a difference?

Comment: You're probably running it in production mode. Maybe you could set it to run in development mode (I dont know how to do it in passanger, but google sure does). Meanwhile you can copy "config.consider_all_requests_local = true" line in config/environments/production.rb and restart the server to see if the error get displayed

Comment: Your passenger is probably misconfigured to point to the app public/ folder.

Comment: @rlecaro2 DreamHost requires you to have your webroot set to public/ in the domain settings. Is that wrong? On a side note, RoR on DreamHost is proving to be a hellscape.

Comment: Have you restarted passenger with every change? You can check the logs in the log folder.

Comment: @rlecaro2 yes - I did, which takes a while when you're going through Dreamhost.

Comment: @itamar the line @jinavar1 (`config.consider_all_requests_local = true`) suggested should be in `config/production.rb`since you're running the server in that environment. Give it a try and check the error in depth. Also, I'd recommend learning the framework in a local machine of yours, instead of some hosting that is making it harder for you to learn.

Comment: @rlecaro2 I'll check back later after I've tried that. Thanks for sticking around through this ridiculousness!

Comment: @itamar Try nitrous.io if your development/hosting environment keeps getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `get "welcome/index"` line or place `root :to => "welcome#index"` at the top of the file.

Comment: Unfortunately this still hasn't fixed the issue. Same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
Quirk::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => "welcome#index"

end
```

I just did the tutorial and runs smoothly http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Maybe you should start the tutorial again in another folder

Comment: I just tried doing that and ran into the exact same issue again.